# Time intervals SQL query

Tags: sql

I need help to aggregate the sequential intervals in one interval
Ms SQL server

Check the image. It describes the case
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MytdR.jpg)

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Share more codes. Also [you can check how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to build the query

1. Use datediff and window function to find out the time difference between previous end time and current start time.
2. Define where we should merge the row. In the provided data, it should be when the difference between previous end_time and current start_time is exactly one minute. whenever we reach a time slot, we use window function to increase the index by +1.
3. Use group by operator and min() and max() to get min_start_time, max_end_time for each time slot.

See the following code as an example:

```
with time_entry_diff AS (
select
   from_time,
   to_time,
   datediff(second,lag(to_time) over (order by from_time),from_time) as time_diff
from
   time_entry
),
time_entry_slot_index AS (
select
   from_time,
   to_time,
   SUM(case when time_diff =60 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by from_time) as timeslot_index
from
   time_entry_diff
)
select
   min(from_time) as from_time,
   max(to_time) as to_time
from
   time_entry_slot_index
group by
   timeslot_index
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78ffc3/32)

[image]

Comment: It worked. I changed the code to be suitable form my procedures and functions. Fantastic. Appreciate, your help.